# Combine 2 Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

Just following Spring Guides http://spring.io/guides#gs I took `gs-rest-service` and `gs-accessing-data-jpa`. Now I want to combine them in one application, and that is where like more understanding of new `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication` is needed.

In `gs-rest-service` config looks emazing, that is almost absent

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`gs-accessing-data-jpa` is more like Spring XML JavaConfig based app.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CopyOfApplication {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(H2).build();
    }

   // 2 other beans...

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CopyOfApplication.class);
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

        //...
    }

}
```

**How to combine them?**

Does it mean that I need to re-write `SpringApplication.run` now on more detailed level ?

Comment: In the spring boot project simply add Spring Data JPA as a dependency... Copy your `CustomerRepository` interface and restart your application. The datasource, transactionmanager etc. will automatically be added by the Spring Boot auto-configuration features.

Comment: Marten, you should maybe just make that explicit in an Answer (not a comment) with a code snippet for the new app. (I don't know why the JPA guide isn't using Spring Boot - maybe we should raise an issue in github against that guide?)

Comment: This is question about Java and new SpringApplication class, dependencies are clear (i.e. just add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Spring Boot application simply add the dependencies from the JPA sample (the ones which you don't already have.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M7")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.0.RC1")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.1.Final")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}
```

or instead of this  you could also use the [spring boot starter project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) for Spring Data JPA. In that case the dependencies would look like the following.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M7")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:0.5.0.M7")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}
```

This will pull in all needed dependencies.

Next copy the `CustomerRepository` to the Spring Boot application. That basically should be everything you need. Spring Boot auto-configure now detects Spring Data JPA and JPA and will bootstrap hibernate, spring data for you.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` (removing the need for 3 of the ORM dependencies)? (Also note that Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE is available.)

Comment: I went for the 1-on-1 copy-paste solution. But instead of these dependencies you could add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I can use `SpringAplication` to get `context`, great.
@DaveSyer could you add your solution as answer if it is different.

Comment: So there is no need for the separate and detailed @Configuration class? I am currently trying to refactor a sample Boot project, but am confused at how it does configuration and autowiring.